# Assigning an asymptotic power to the volume form?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, asymptotics

I was reading about the covariant theory of asymptotic symmetries in this review:

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0111246

I have a question about eq. (1.8), but before I ask I should describe what the problem is. In the review above they consider some Lagrangian $L(\phi^i)$ which depends on fields $\phi^i$ which can be decomposed into background fields $\bar \phi^i$ and the respective deviations $\varphi^i$ as follows:

$$\phi^i=\bar\phi^i+\varphi^i$$

The deviation is supposed to vanish asymptotically as a certain boundary is approached in target space variables. This is denoted as $\varphi_i\rightarrow O(\chi^i)$. For example, if we talk about gravity, the fields $\phi_i$ could be the components of the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$. Let's take for illustration the component

$$g_{rr}=1+\frac{c}{r}$$

Considering $r=\infty$ to be the boundary of interest in this illustration, we could identify:

$$\phi=g_{rr}~~~,~~~\bar\phi=1~~~,~~~\varphi=\frac{c}{r}$$

Which means $\varphi\rightarrow O(r^{-1})$. We say that $\varphi$ is "of order" $r^{-1}$ as we take $r\rightarrow \infty$.
Now, let us take a look at the eq. (1.8) from the review above. It roughly says:

$$\forall\varphi^i\rightarrow O(\chi^i)~:~\frac{\delta L}{\delta\varphi_i}d^nx\to O(\chi_i)$$

Which means that for all deviation fields $\varphi^i$ satisfying the asymptotics $\varphi^i\to O(\chi^i)$ the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equations times the volume form should have asymptotic behavior $O(\chi_i)$ (notice that the notation is deceivingly similar but $\chi^i\neq\chi_i$). Now, in order to translate this to the above illustration in terms of GR, we could consider the Lagrangian

$$L=\sqrt{-g}R$$

where $g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor and $R$ is the Ricci scalar. The corresponding Euler-Lagrange equations would be

$$\frac{\delta L}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}=\sqrt{-g}\left(R^{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}R\right)$$

with Ricci tensor $R^{\mu\nu}$. To get the relevant asymptotic behavior of the Euler-Lagrange term we should consider an expansion around $r\to\infty$ and isolate the linearized term. However, apparently the volume form $d^nx$ also has a certain asymptotic behavior under $r\to\infty$? This is the point which is unclear to me. I am used to thinking of the volume form as a bunch of differential forms which normally do not care about it if the corresponding variables approach any specific values. As a further example, in the same review above, right before eq. (6.40) the volume form of $AdS_3$ is assigned the order $d^3x\to O(r)$ as $r\to\infty$. I wonder how this power law for the volume form is obtained? Is it $O(r)$ because there is only one angle in $AdS_3$, and it would be $O(r^k)$ for a $k-$sphere in an $AdS_{2+k}$? Or is it always $O(r)$ because $d^3x$ contains only one $dr$ which we should consider as being "integrated" to $r$? Basically, an explanation on how exactly a volume form can get an asymptotic behavior assigned to it is very welcome! Thank you for any suggestion.

**EDIT**

To make the problem I have a bit more clear, take a look at the article

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form

The section "Riemannian Volume Form" has an expression for a usual volume form in local coordinates:

$$\omega=\sqrt{|g|}dx_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_n$$

Of course, one could argue that the factor $\sqrt{|g|}$ could produce a direct variable dependence of the volume form. However, as far as I know, in GR the factor $\sqrt{-g}$ in the lagrangian is already exactly this "Jacobian" that takes care of transformations, so that we would have it twice if we included it again in the volume form $d^nx$. This is why I am pretty sure that $d^nx=dx_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_n$ in the above arxive review, hence my confusion.